# HTML5 Binary Button

Tags: html, button

I'm building an webapp using HTML5, PHP, AJAX and CSS. I want to add for settings a binary button like in Android and iOS. But I do not how use such button in HTML5. A normal button is made like this code: `"<button onclick=""></button>`. But how can I add two possible stages for this button? Like a checkbox in a button format?

Comment: Wrapper with images and hidden checkbox. Images changes with JS code.

Comment: How do I get from this checkbox symbol a button?

Comment: Check source of http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#buttons